# Google sheets: append data from 2 tabs, with different column order

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 tabs named S1 and S2. They both contain 3 columns of data (A, B and C). I just want to merge their content in a 3rd tab, using functions. Issue is that the order of columns is different in S1 and S2.
[S1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVYC.png)
[S2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjpb3.png)

S1
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | A        | DeptA    |
| 2        | B        | DeptB    |
| 3        | C        | DeptC    |

S2
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 4        | DeptD    | D        |
| 5        | DeptE    | E        |
| 6        | DeptF    | F        |

What I want to get in a 3rd tab is:
| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | A        | DeptA    |
| 2        | B        | DeptB    |
| 3        | C        | DeptC    |
| 4        | D        | DeptD    |
| 5        | E        | DeptE    |
| 6        | F        | DeptF    |

I'm using the following formula: "query({'S1'!A1:C;'S2'!A2:A,'S2'!C2:C,'S2'!B2:B};"Select Col1, Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null";1)". But I get a formula analysis error.
I have also tried "

```
={
     query({S1!A1:C},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3");
         query({S2!A2:C},"Select Col1,Col3,Col2")
}
```

"
But I also get a formula analysis error

Spreadsheet access: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FdaRSANfcqMkSBE-is8ek8bFWp80vVW8P3a-v0q4MwU/edit?usp=share_link

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on locale setting its either:

`=query({{'S1'!A1:C};{'S2'!A2:A\'S2'!C2:C\'S2'!B2:B}};"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null")`

OR

`=query({{'S1'!A1:C};{'S2'!A2:A,'S2'!C2:C,'S2'!B2:B}},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null")`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your Locale Settings. You should use semi-colons instead of commas:

```
={
     query({'S1'!A1:C};"Select Col1,Col2,Col3");
         query({'S2'!A2:C};"Select Col1,Col3,Col2")
}
```